# How to take value using regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have such a string "Categ=All&Search=Jucs&Kin=LUU".How to get an array of values from this line [All,Jucs,LUU].

Here is an example

```
let x = /(\b\w+)$|(\b\w+)\b&/g;
let y = "Categories=All&Search=Filus";
console.log(y.match(x));
```

but I wanted no character &.

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: What are the rules for matching here? How does the first example differ from the last example?

Comment: what  is the condition for last string ? it should be [how,do,run,lots,WW,11www] ,if compared to other strings

Comment: You are asking 4 different questions here. Please read: [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223)

Answer (score 2):

Since this looks like a URL query string, you can treat it as one and parse the data without needing a regex.

```js
let query = "Categ=All&Search=Jucs&Kin=LUU",
    parser = new URLSearchParams(query),
    values = [];

parser.forEach(function(v, k){
    values.push(v);
});

console.log(values);
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Note: This may not work in IE, if that's something you care about.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all matches and take only the first group, ignoring the =

```js
let x = /=([^&]+)/g;
let y = "Categories=All&Search=Filus";
let match;
while (match = x.exec(y)) {
  console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using split and filter with index  to separate Keys and values
1. Use **split([^A-Za-z0-9])** to split string based on any special character other letters and numbers
2. Use Filter and index to get even or odd elements of array for keys and values

```js
var str1 = "Categ=All&Search=Jucs&Kin=LUU";
    
    
function splitter(str, index){
  return str.split(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/).filter((v,i)=>i%2=== index); 
} 

console.log(splitter(str1, 0)) //["Categ", "Search", "Kin"]
console.log(splitter(str1, 1))//["All", "Jucs", "LUU"]
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/yWMYwz?editors=1010